# "Naviagate to related view" notation in editor margin

Tags: intellij-idea

I am getting the 5 icons in the margin of an editor for a Spring Controller.  The mouse-over says "Navigate to related view".  How can I get rid of the multiples?

I can live with 1, but definitely don't need 5.   All 5 icons take me to the same line of a JSP.

Intellij 13.0.1

[image: Margin]

Comment: I think that it's a bug since version 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug -- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118558 -- that is fixed and will be in 13.0.2.